# Calculate Dynamic Sum based of specific column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to do the following in Power BI using DAX

I have a value that i want to SUM and then multiply by the number of weeks in a specific month.

[image]

So the first two rows will be SUM(Value)/WeeksInMonth = SUM(100+200)/5.

Then for Feb it will be SUM(300+100+200+400)/4

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all you need is a measure. You can use something like this:

```
Measure1 = Sum('Table'[Value])/Min('Table'[Weeks in Month])
```

Answer (score 0):

I just created it as a measure and used it in a new measure:

```
MeasureCalc = (sum(Sales[Amount])/Sales[WeekInMonth])
```

the WeekInMonth measure is

```
WeekInMonth = (MIN(Sales[WeeksInMonth]))
```